# How can predifined code be called with exec()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec

Is it possible to call predefined code using `exec()`?

```
In[0]
exec(f"var{1} = 55")
print(var1)
print(exec(f"var{1}"))

Out[0]
55
None
```

I'm predefining `var1` as `55,` but when I tried to call the variable using `exec` it return `None`.

Can I call my variable using `exec()`?

Comment: `exec` executes the code as a statement and statements don’t return anything. `eval` evaluates code as an expression, however.

Comment: See the docs for [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) and [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval). `exec` updates given globals and locals dicts, and returns `None`.  As an aside, `f"var{1}"` is confusing.... its jsut `"var1"`.